# Keyboard and Mouse (Touchpad) not working after upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, mouse, 17.04

Today I **upgraded** my Ubuntu from **16.04 to 17.04** and after the upgrade my **keyboard and mouse (touchpad) are not working anymore**. I am not able to log into Ubuntu. Please help me I have very important data on the computer. How can I solve this? 
I have We are back in the Philippines. We are generally doing well, although
the first weeks in the Philippines have not been as smooth as other
times, but God has always provided a solution for the hiccups..

Comment: I can't understand why people do that: upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04. You upgrade from an LTS to a non-LTS, and the upgrade pass is not tested by developers. It is ridiculous. Install 16.04 and don't do it again.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a newbie. I don't have that much knowledge about it.i just got prompt in Ubuntu about the upgrade and I upgraded it simply. is there any way to Rollback to 16.04?

Comment: You got that prompt because you deliberately changed the default setting to notify about non-LTS releases. There is no way to roll back. There may be a way to fix your issue, but there is no information in your question to suggest one.

Comment: The main problem is I upgraded simply and rebooted and Keyboard and mouse(touchpad ) are not working. now simply I am seeing login screen but I am not able to do anything because mouse and keyboard are not working.please help me I have important data

Comment: You can always boot with a LiveUSB and copy your importand data.

Comment: Yes, I used Linux reader and retrieved all the data from my windows .Thanks for your time I really appreciate